# Convert same string variable to string[]

Tags: c#

How can I (if possible) convert same string variable to string array without initializing a new string array variable like:

```
    var pairArr= pair.Split(" - ").ToArray();
```

I tried:

```
pair.Split(" - ").ToArray();
```

or:

```
pair.Split(" - ").Select(a=>a.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

then when i use pair[0] or pair[1] it gets the chars[0] or [1]

```
pair.Split(" - ").ToArray();

            if (pair[0].ToString()==mainPerson.Name || 
pair[0].ToString()==mainPerson.Birthday) 
            {
                foreach (var person in fullPerson)
                {
                    if (pair[1].ToString()==person.Name || 
pair[1].ToString()==person.Birthday)
                    {
                        children.Add(new Person(person.Name, 
person.Birthday));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Split() returns an array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that directly in the `if` block
.

```
 if (pair.Split(" - ")[0]==mainPerson.Name || pair.Split(" - ")[0]==mainPerson.Birthday) 
 {
     //Do something
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split string by another string using the overload of `string.Split`:

```
 var pair = "Mike - Peter";
 var pairArr = pair.Split(new[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
 pairArr[0] // "Mike"
 pairArr[1] // "Peter"
```